# Chance of drawing 4 red marbles out of a big bag.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

In a bag with an infinite number of marbles, where a third are red, a third are green and a third are blue. Given that you pick $10$ marbles, of which $3$ are blue, what are the chances of picking $4$ red ones?

I've tried looking for an answer in the form of $\overline3^3\times\overline3^6\times{a\choose b}$, but I'm not really sure if that is the correct way of doing it... Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Given that exactly $3$ out of $10$ marbles are blue, we are left with $2$ other colors and $7$ marbles. The chance of picking $4$ red marbles (conditioned on the event that exactly $3$ are blue) would then be $\left(\frac 12\right)^7 \binom{7}{4}$. $\frac 12$ corresponds to the equal chance of each unknown marble being red or green.

**Old Answer (to a different question, out of misunderstanding)**

The three blue marbles you picked would not make a difference. You just need to find the chance of getting $4$ red marbles from picking $7$ marbles. You can compute this directly or relate the number of picked red marbles to the binomial distribution with $p = 1/3$ and $n = 7$. Either way, the answer is $\left(\frac 13\right)^4\left(\frac 23\right)^3\binom{7}{4}$. $\left(\frac 13\right)^4$ is the chance that $4$ picks result in red. $\left(\frac 23\right)^3$ is the chance that $3$ picks result in non-red. $\binom 74$ is the number of ways you can "mix up" the red and non-red picks.

Comment: Wouldn't $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3$ allow for more than $3$ blue marbles to be drawn?

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood the question. I thought it was done in stages. I will correct accordingly.